# Why did the United Earth Forces name their hover tank brigade after the Robotech Masters’ home system?

Tags: robotech

In the Western Robotech composite series, the Army of the Southern Cross was part of the United Earth Forces, the army focused on in the second Robotech saga, *The Robotech Masters*, which chronicled the Second Robotech War and utilized the Spartas Veritech Hovertank.

The Army was originally named after the cross-like constellation of stars in which Tirol (the homeworld of the Robotech Masters) was located; a constellation that was only visible from the southern hemisphere on Earth.

Was this just an ill-planned coincidence to name the Earth’s premier army who would come to fight the Robotech Masters, in honor of the Robotech Masters home or was something else going on with this connection?

Comment: In real military history, especially modern western history, it's not at all uncommon to name an army after the place they are fighting.  See "Afrika Korps," the "British Army of the Rhine" (various incarnations), etc.

Comment: In the US Civil War many of the US field armies were named after rivers, like the Army of the Potomac, the Army of the Ohio, the Army of the Cumberland, the Army of the Tennessee, etc.  The Ohio and Potomac rivers were more or less on the border between loyal and rebel or potentially rebel states, and the Cumberland and Tennessee rivers led deep into rebel territory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the most authoritative source appears to be Carl Macek’s [notes about his development of the composite series including coordination of *Southern Cross* within the larger Robotech series.](https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/things-you-didn-t-know-about-the-creation-of-robotech/?amp)

Unfortunately, there is nothing about the “Southern Cross” name.

The best answer is suggested by @DavidW:

> In real military history, especially modern western history, it's not at all uncommon to name an army after the place they are fighting. See "Afrika Korps," the "British Army of the Rhine" (various incarnations), etc.

This was expanded by @M.A.Golding:

> In the US Civil War many of the US field armies were named after rivers, like the Army of the Potomac, the Army of the Ohio, the Army of the Cumberland, the Army of the Tennessee, etc. The Ohio and Potomac rivers were more or less on the border between loyal and rebel or potentially rebel states, and the Cumberland and Tennessee rivers led deep into rebel territory.